# I have been given 9 balls numbered $1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 $. What is the probability of selecting a $5$ and a $7$ with replacement?

Tags: probability

**I have been given 9 balls numbered $1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 $. What is the probability of selecting a $5$ and a $7$ with replacement ?**

**My Attempt :** Sample space of this random experiment will be $\{(a,b) : a , b \in \{1 , 2 , .... , 9\} \}$. Here $(a,b)$ is not an order pair . Clearly , this sample space will contain $9 \choose 2$$+9 = 45$ outcomes.

So probability of selecting a $5$ and a $7$ will be $\frac{1}{45}$ and selecting an ordered pair $(5,7)$ is $\frac{1}{90}$.

Have I gone wrong anywhere ? Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: It is possible for your selection to be any ordered pair. By saying "select with replacement" there is a first selection of a particular number from 1 to 9. Then "replacement" simply means that first selected number is put back in and you select your second number from the same set 1 to 9. So for example $(2,5)$ is a different choice with replacement than is $(5,2)$ because in the first the 2 is selected first, while in the second it is the 5 selected first.

Answer (score 2):

Since draws are made with replacement, each time there will be $9$ choices, thus the equiprobable sample space has $(9\times 9) = 81$ points

And the desired probability is $\;\dfrac{2\cdot1}{9\cdot9} = \dfrac 2{81}$

---

*Re OP's doubts in comment*

- You are badly mixing up draws with replacement and draws without replacement. The question clearly mentions *with replacement*
- Also, for draws without replacement, the sample space would just be $\binom92$ You added an extra $9$ for cases like two $1's$ etc, but these **are not possible** when you aren't replacing a drawn number.
- The formula for draws without replacement of getting a $5$ and a $7$ would thus be $\dfrac{\binom22}{\binom92} = \dfrac 1{36}$

Comment: I could not understand. Please elaborate little bit.  Can you please tell me where I have gone wrong ?@true blue anil

Comment: I will add further explanation in the body